# Generated ObjectId for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I'd need to generate `ObjectId` for my entities before I save them to `MongoDB`. I generate it simply with `new org.bson.types.ObjectId()`. It creates an object `_id` which is a quaternion of `_time`, `_machine`, `_inc` and `_new`. The value of `_id` itself looks like a normal `MongoDB` `_id`. Nevertheless after transforming to `JSON` and sending it to database, it's saved as an array of four elements. Is there any way how to make it to look like `ObjectId` generated by `MongoDB` - `"_id" : ObjectId("54edaa41ca190ebda00a2abd")` without any text preoprocessing?

Comment: Why do you have to transform it to json before saving the entities?

Comment: @blubear Is there any better approach to save objects to `MongoDB` than   `BasicDBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(myObject); collection.save(dbObject);` ?

Comment: Can you generate the ObjectId objects after you created the BasicDBObject object?

Comment: No..that's the problem - I have to work with `ObjectId` already within the service layer - I need to store it as a reference for other objects and so. So I create the object, edit its variables and then want to save it.

Comment: In that case I think there is no helping it, you will need to do more than simply casting the result of JSON.parse as BasicDBObject. I'm not too familiar with Java, so let's hope others could come up with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple Java program works.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
ObjectId objectId = ObjectId.get();
DB test1 = mongoClient.getDB("test1");
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject("_id",objectId)
.append("key", "value");
test1.getCollection("test").insert(dbObject);
```

Now query with Shell, ObjectId is saved correctly.

```
> use test1
switched to db test1
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55520a15b8a0e51f45921946"), "key" : "value" }
```

Comment: This won't help as I need to generate `ObjectId` before I create `BasicDBObject`

Comment: Is the same, if you generate objectId before and pass it to the BasicDBObject. See the edition. Maybe I didn't understand you.